# Convert an java file into android program

Tags: java, android

hi i am a new android developer. When i am searching for a logic related to my app in google, i found a java application which is related to my android app. After making some changes i succeded in getting output, but i need the code to be in an android based project. When i change to convert it i get lot of errors, is there any possible way to convert the java application into an android app by including any external jar file..... The java application is just a part of my android app, based on that i have to develop more so pls help me....

thanx in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to include external Java code via **.jar** files, that is supported in Android. Just put the file into the `libs/` directory of your Android project and use the classes as you would somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse IDE, this might help:
After including the .jar files in the libs/ folder, right click on the required .jar file and select "build path", then click on "add to build path". After doing this, u'll notice that the .jar file is added in the "Referenced libraries" in your project. Once done, you are all good to go and import methods from these files. Hope that helps you remove your errors. Happy coding. :)

Comment: I'm assuming these instructions are IDE specific in which case it would be useful to mention which IDE the instructions are for.